# One hookup docking station / port replicator

Tags: macbook-pro, display, lightning

They just got me (my very first ever) macbook pro at work.  I am really digging it thus far. One thing I would really like to do is "dock it" to my existing rig.. two dvi displays, keyboard, mouse, etc.

I know apple doesn't do docking stations so I was wondering what my options are?  So far it looks like I am going to have to plug and unplug up to 4 cables to accommodate my setup.  This is totally a pain.  I dock and undock my current laptop up to 5 times a day.  I don't want to have to mess will all these wires every time.  I thought apple was antiwire?

**Ideally what I would like is:
One cable (thunderbolt?) that goes to a box that has two high resolution ports for displays (dvi, hdmi, displayport, etc) and a few usb ports for my keyboard, mouse, and other miscellaneous stuff.**

I don't suppose that could also power my macbook?  If not, then I will just have to live with two cables I suppose.

So far I can only find these "boxes" with just one hi-res port.

Answer (score 1):

There are few docking solutions available for MacBooks:

- [Belkin Thunderbolt™ Express Dock](http://www.belkin.com/us/F4U055-Belkin/p/P-F4U055/)
- [Belkin USB 3.0 Universal Docking Station with Dual DVI](http://www.belkin.com/us/B2B122-Belkin/p/P-B2B122/)
- [Henge Docks' Horizontal Dock](http://hengedocks.com/pages/horizontal-mac-dock) *preorder
- [Zenboxx Zendock](http://zenboxx.com) *kickstarter
- [LandingZone](http://landingzone.net)

There are probably few more options that were not listed above.

More info on [Thunderbolt ports and displays: Frequently asked questions (FAQ)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219)

Comment: Wow, these are great! I want one the "real" docks. So if I use one of the Thunderbolt hubs, then all I would need to so is get some thunderbolt to DVI connectors?

Comment: what about hubs that include a dvi? [link](http://goo.gl/Hm8vsB). Then I can hook up two non thunderbolt displays right? Convert one TB to DVI and convert one HDMI to DVI. This seems like a viable solution?

Comment: There are some constraints about using thunderbolt adapters with daisy chain thunderbolt connections. Read more on FAQ on the answer. Every Mac have a limit on how many displays it can handle. But you can also add USB displays if you really need to.

Answer (score 1):

Another more simple solution is the Kickstarter project Bracket

- [Bracket](http://kickstarter.com/projects/181279175/bracket-the-macbook-pro-retina-cable-dock)